# Manually setting session ID in Express

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, express, passport.js

I have an Angular/Express app and am trying to implement some kind of restful auth. The Express app has Passport standard username/pass login and Redis sessions. On successful login I return the session ID and angular then sends this to every request in the headers. The problem is that I don't know how to make Express make use of this as the session ID. I have tried writing to req.sessionId in middleware with no success.

How can I use headers or query string as a way to send the session id along.

Comment: I would guess, that when angular got the sessionId it will send it with every request, most likely as a cookie header. How did you check that the an angular request arrived at your express server containing the sessionId? Maybe everything is working already, I suggest you measure, if a request stretches the express sessionTimout.

Comment: @angabriel things work fine with cookies/session - but I am exploring alternatives as I want to authenticate on cross domains - I can get the session ID but can't seem to use another way to set it

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem.  This seems to be working for me, try it out and let me know if it works for you:

```
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
    // I'm pulling it from the query string. You could use headers.
    if (req.query.session) {
        req.sessionID = req.query.session;
        req.sessionStore.get(req.query.session, function (err, sess) {
            // This attaches the session to the req.
            req.sessionStore.createSession(req, sess);
            next()
        })
    } else {
        next()
    }
})
```

The downside is it does get the session twice.  I should write a subclass of the session handler, but I'm being lazy for now.

UPDATE:
I decided to get un-lazy and fork express-session.  I submitted a pull request, but until then you can find it [here](https://github.com/tim-dev/session).